# How to manually install SocketRocket in telegram app (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, telegram, socketrocket

I'm installed socketRocket in telegram via cocoa pods but Error occurred.
how to the right way to install socket rocket via cocoa pods or the best way to install socket rocket in the telegram?

Comment: Are you closed your Xcode after integration

Comment: Cocoa pods is best way to integrate any framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not reopened your Xcode after integration of your framework. First close Xcode and reopen white coloured Xcode [Initially blue coloured Xcode with Projectname.xcodeproj, later it's creates one more file, that is Projectname.xcworkspace]. You need to open this second file(Newly created file). If this not solved your problem send your error.

Comment: my problem is: in this app already created "xcworkspace" and but I do not know what is the target in cocoa pods in this app!!!

Comment: ok, I want to install socket rocket in telegram but I do not know to do it.

Comment: please help me instalation to step by step socket rocket in telegram with cocoa pods.

Comment: Are you new to ios

Comment: no, I can to install socket rocket in other app but I can't install in the telegram